# On design of a (preferrably unimodular) matrix

Tags: matrices, lattices, diophantine-equations, integer-programming, operator-norms

Assume each entry is in $\Bbb Z$.

Say we want to solve $Ax=b$ where known $A$ is $n\times n$, unknown $x$ is $n\times1$ and $b$ is $n\times1$.

The absolute value of minors of augmented matrix $[A|b]$ is [related](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1989-105-04/S0002-9939-1989-0955458-1/S0002-9939-1989-0955458-1.pdf) to infinity norm of solution of $x$.

> Given $p>0$ what is the smallest $n$ such that there is a full rank $A$ (preferably unimodular) and assignment of all but one entry of vector $b$ such that given positive integer input $a\in(\beta p,p)$ where $\beta\in(0,1)$ holds if we place $a$ in the remaining entry of $b$ then absolute value of largest minor of augmented matrix $[A|b]$ is at most $\sqrt p$?

Comment: Thinking more I think it is impossible if you ask for full rank.